# Parametric versus nonparametric AUC from ROC curve

Tags: spss, roc, auc

SPSS offers two ways to estimate Area Under the Curve (AUC) and its standard error, that is nonparametricly using trapezoidal rule or parametrically using binegative exponential distribution. I have been using nonparametric method for all my analysis. So when is it more appropriate to use parametric method? Is it when there is ties in the score and there outcome classification is based on ordinal scale score with limited range? I heard that nonparametric AUC is systematically underestimated when there are ties. Is it still recommended to interpret the results despite having ties?